# Why does pyodbc generate garbled error messages on Fedora 27 ppc64?

Tags: python, python-3.x, fedora, pyodbc

I'm using pyodbc (3.0.10-9) with Python 3 (3.6.6-1) on Fedora 27 ppc64 (on an IBM Power 720). I have a very simple script that connects to a MS SQL Server (2K8R2 on W2K8R2) database table as follows:

```
import time
import pyodbc
# import pyximport; pyximport.install()

def main():
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DSN=something;UID=uu;PWD=pppp;', ansi=True)

    cursor = cnxn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM dbo.tb_Table;')

    for row in cursor:
        print(row)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    time.sleep(3)
    main()
    input()
```

If the UID and PWD are correct, everything runs fine.

So I stopped the SQL Server service on the Windows server, in order to see the error message on the Power7 machine.

However, I am getting this garbled error on a Mac OSX (10.11.6) terminal and on the Fedora 27 gnome-terminal:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "podbc.py", line 16, in <module>
    main()
  File "podbc.py", line 6, in main
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DSN=something;UID=uu;PWD=pppp;', ansi=True)
pyodbc.OperationalError: ('08S01', '[08S01] 嬀䘀爀攀攀吀䐀匀崀嬀匀儀䰀\u2000匀攀爀瘀攀爀崀唀渀愀戀氀攀\u2000琀漀\u2000挀漀渀渀攀挀琀㨀\u2000䄀搀愀瀀琀椀瘀攀\u2000匀攀爀瘀攀爀\u2000椀猀\u2000甀渀愀瘀愀椀氀愀戀氀攀\u2000漀爀\u2000搀漀攀猀\u2000渀漀琀\u2000攀砀椀猀琀 (20009) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

Why? How can I "translate" this into a readable (english) form?

Any help or pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pyodbc 3.0.10 is very old. Upgrade to the most recent version (currently 4.0.24). It includes the fix for [this issue](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/251).

**Update:**

You have a classic case of [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake). ppc64 defaults to big-endian byte ordering but Microsoft SQL Server (and hence FreeTDS) use little-endian byte ordering so the UTF_16-encoded message returned from the server is being mangled:

```
>>> foo = '嬀䘀爀攀攀吀䐀匀崀嬀匀儀䰀\u2000匀攀爀瘀攀爀崀唀渀愀戀氀攀\u2000琀漀\u2000挀漀渀渀攀挀琀㨀\u2000䄀搀愀瀀琀椀瘀攀\u2000匀攀爀瘀攀爀\u2000椀猀\u2000甀渀愀瘀愀椀氀愀戀氀攀\u2000漀爀\u2000搀漀攀猀\u2000渀漀琀\u2000攀砀椀猀琀'
>>> foo.encode('utf-16be').decode('utf-16le')
'[FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist'
```

Normally one would use pyodbc's `Connection.setdecoding` method (described [here](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Unicode)) to work around the mismatch in endian-ness, but your error is happening before the connection is established. You may want to raise an [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues) regarding your particular circumstances.

Comment: Downloaded the latest tar.gz, installed with pip and pip3 (--upgrade option on both). Checked with pip freeze and pip3 freeze. I now have pyodbc==4.0.24 (on Python 2 and 3). Still the same garbled error message persists. Any ideas?

Comment: @Molasar - Which ODBC driver are you using? Microsoft's "ODBC Driver xx for SQL Server"...? FreeTDS...? ...? Also, what version is it?

Comment: I am using my distro's packages: unixODBC-2.3.4-7.fc27.ppc64.rpm and freetds-1.00.38-4.fc27.ppc64.rpm. I believe there is no Microsoft ODBC driver for my distro's arch (ppc64)...